# Git Сменить origin

Tags: git, heroku

Когда-то я залил свой проект на gitlab. Потом, не помню уже как, сменил origin на heroku, так как нужно было залить сам проект на heroku. Позже я переделал проект, залил его на heroku, и у меня не выходит сменить origin на gitlab (скорее всего я просто глуп и не помню всего этого, работа с гитом для меня пока очень сложна)

Я ещё, насмотревшись туториалов, зачем-то создал в репозитории на гитлаб три ветки, в итоге поместив проект на две других, а на ветке master - шиш с маслом. Теперь решил, что так дело не пойдёт, и надо:

1. Как-то удалить все ветки, кроме master, переместив на неё все файлы с любой другой ветки (там идентичные файлы);
2. И, залить новый коммит на гитлаб;

В общем, тут всё очевидно - просто хочу сделать всё, как у людей, а не ту тяп-ляп, что у меня сейчас - самому смотреть больно...

Comment: Ветки не надо удалять.  Надо просто слить изменения с них в `master`(читать `git merge`). Вам не обязательно иметь только один репозиторий. Почитайте подробнее по словам `git remote`. На развернутый ответ нет времени сейчас(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала нужно замержить одну из веток (любую, если они действительно одинаковые) в master:

1. Переключитесь на master: `git checkout master`
2. Замержить ветку в мастер: `git merge <название ветки>`

Потом, нужно обновить origin (ссылку на удаленный репозиторий), вообще вместо того, чтобы каждый раз не менять ссылки с GitLab на Heroku и обратно, можно создать несколько remote, один будет ссылаться на GitLab, другой на Heroku:

1. Чтобы переключиться на GitLab: `git remote set-url origin <ссылка на git репозиторий с GitLab>`
2. Чтобы создать второй: `git remote add heroku <ссылка>`
3. Потом можно будет пушить в нужный репозиторий: `git push origin` или `git push heroku`

А уже после того, как все сделаете, чтобы можно будет и удалить ветки (перед этим проверьте, что действительно master был запушен): `git branch -D <название ветки>`

Ссылки:
[Обновление origin (eng)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url)
[Работа с remote (eng)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Comment: Раз старое содержимое master'а не нужно, я бы вместо merge сделал `git reset --hard <ветка_или_коммит>`.