# Как помнять репозиторй в GitHub

Tags: c#, github

Как отключить проект от github   и поменять репозиторий на другой ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Git Сменить origin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1027287/git-%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-origin)

Answer (score 0):

1. Удали его с GitHub, в настройках проекта, в конце(Только сначала выкачай его)
2. Создай repository на своём сервере([клац](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)) или локально([клац](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository))
3. Всё :)

Comment: удалять совсем необязательно

Comment: Я дума отключить, это удалить.Но мож просто сделать его приватным

Comment: репозиторию удалил теперь прказывает что прога связана с GIT  и не могу добавить новою сылку на репо вот как это сделать ?

Comment: Включи скрытые папки и в корне программы будет .git (Удали его и сделай пункт №2 из моего ответа :) )

Answer (score 0):

если вкратце, то

git remote set-url origin http://.....

Более детально читать тут:

https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url